# After copy/paste class files, IBActions in one project remain hooked to their original story board

Tags: ios, storyboard

I created a new project in which I want to reuse classes and story board elements from another project. I thought it would be simple.
I copied the classes that I needed. They were initially tied to storyboard elements through IBActions.

When I open the second project - the one where components are reused - the IBActions point to the Story boards elements of the first project !!!

At this point, in the second project the story board is empty, so when I mouse-over the IBAction target in say ClassA file, the button in the first project is highlighted ....

How can I get rid of this thing ?
EDIT:get rid of this without having to break the IBActions links in the IB....
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of inter-related issues

- when you added the classes to your new project, you did not check the "destination" checkbox "copy items into destination group's folder", so the classes as listed in the new project are just references to the original project class files. That is why the IBActions point to the storyboard elements in the first project.
- if you do check that checkbox, and *copy* the classes into your new project, all links with storyboard items disappear and you have to relink everything with items in your new storyboard.

Comment: Hi, actually I copied them manually with Finder, not with XCode. I checked the files were not copied as links as well. It surely is a mistake on my side, but can't find the root cause.

Comment: @Alex, best to create a new project using one of XCode project templates, then "add files" to project (by dragging or using the menu) selecting classes you want to copy &check that "copy items" box. That should break your old IBAction and IBOutlet links. Try with your existing project by deleting the files you have imported and re-copying them as described.

Comment: Ok, that's probably the reason, though it doesn't make much sense. I refactored the classes, which broke the links. I'll remember the advice for next time. Thanks !

Comment: I selected the "copy items if needed" opttion but the link to the old sotryboard still remains.  I am using XCode 6.